# Update authentication

Tags: updates

When I try to get updates I see an Authentication required dialog box.  I tried the password  I set-up during installation but is fails.  What is the authentication?

Comment: Be specific.

If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer. [How do I ask a good question?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: By any chance did you change your keyboard layout *after* the installation to something different used during the installation?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you've forgotten your password (check caps lock, typos etc) you can try and reset it using recovery mode as per https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password. Should be similar for elementary OS.